# Best routine to lose weight?

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, body-fat, jogging

I am wanting to lose half a stone maybe a stone before the years out. I have just started. I am doing a intense 15 minute work out (push ups, planks, star jumps, forward lounges etc) then 3 different sets of sit ups doing 30 of each then a mile jog at night. Does this seem sufficient? Any other non gym and non equipment ways of losing the weight?

Comment: Apologies never do a search

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific which will cause you to lose weight. Being in a caloric deficit will do that. Amy exercise that helps you lose weight is simply because it puts you in a caloric deficit meaning you are burning more calories than you are taking in.
Is 15 minutes of any exercise really enough to put you in a major deficit that would cause significant weight loss ? Probablyy not

Comment: Fvck me Yisrael you have made me actually freak out a bit haha. I thought I was doing well! It is fast and intense 15 minutes though. You defo know you have been in work out by the end. So should I step it up then I take it? 2 hours a day?

Comment: I would take a look at your eating plan first. If you don't want to do that and you are currently maintaining your weight over a period of a few months then I would focus on cardio as that will burn the most calories. So try to get in a few mile run or walk fast pace. Bear in mind that if you eat more do to exercising you possibly won't lose weight and might even gain

Comment: @yisrael is right. Exercise can help you keep your weight, but loosing weight is purely an "energyIntake-energyUse" function. If you spend more energy than you consume, you will loose weight. Note though that the body have all sorts of smarts to conserve energy when it is in a deficit. So usually, you loose weight in the very beginning and then the body makes up for this by being more energy efficient. Exercises can then help keep the energy usage higher than what would otherwise be the case.